# Can you track google ads conversions between two subdomanis

Tags: cookies, google-ads-api

Can you track google ad conversion from google ad click to example.com them to subdomain.example.com?

We have configured conversion tracking for two types of users.

1. Client Users / Signup
2. Freelancer Users / Signup

These users first visit example.com. On example.com they click signup button which takes them to app.example.com to signup using aws amplify. They first signup to cognito then after that an account is created for them our internal database. After that we a send a conversion to google ads via a click.

Only Freelancer conversions are recorded. Client conversions are not recorded. We have setup two primary conversion actions

1. Freelancers
2. Clients

We have setup two secondary actions

1. Freelancers just complete cognito signup
2. Clients just complete cognito signup

Only conversion actions for freelancers are working both secondary and primary.
I diagonised the tags using tagassistant and all tags are firing.

What could be wrong in my setup.